# Python Multiple Dataframe with array - Unable to coerce to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am doing a simple multiplication between a 1xN Dataframe with a Nx1 NumpyArray, but I obtain a error: "ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (1, 4): given (4, 1)"

The image below shows better the error and the code.
Any suggestion? Thank you!

[image: Problem and code description]

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, on one hand you are trying to multiply a Numpy Array with a Pandas DataFrame (which is asking for troubles), and on the other, even though the previous operation would be allowed, both data structures do not have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see,Beta1 is a numpy array and X_avg is a dataframe.so you need to get numpy version of X_avg to perform the multiplication.Use [to_numpy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) to get the numpy array of a dataframe.

```
Beta0 = Beta1*X_avg.to_numpy()
```

Also you can use beautiful [dot product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) to get the result as well.

```
Beta0 = np.dot(Beta1,X_avg.to_numpy())
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Helped a lot!